# How to use Tkinter to open file in folder using dropdown

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, file-handling

I need help on how to make a button after I choose a folder in dropdown list.

For Example: I have 3 folders name "Folder 1","Folder 2" & "Folder 3". Inside "Folder 1", I have 5 excel(.xlsx) files. So I need help on how to read and display the data in 1 excel(.xlsx) file.

My current situation: I choose "Folder 1" in the dropdown menu. The next thing that I need is a button which can open the "Folder 1"  and display the other list of 5 excel(.xlsx) files. And then, I can choose one of the excel(.xlsx) file and display the data inside the gui.

Here is my code.... Help me    :'(

---

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
#import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk
folder = r'C:\Users\test folder'
filelist = [fname for fname in os.listdir(folder)]
master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry('1200x800')
master.title('Select a file')
optmenu = ttk.Combobox(master, values=filelist, state='readonly')
optmenu.pack(fill='x')
master.mainloop()
```

---

Comment: Displaying excel file in tkinter is another question and choosing file is another one.

Comment: I think what your looking for is `glob`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just select and read a file's contents from tkinter. You have to write some other scripts for that reading part.

What the selection of filename does from tkinter `combo box`, is nothing but, get the particular file name as a `string` type.

However, in Python it's pretty straight forward to read a `.xlsx file`.
You can use `Pandas` module for that.

I have written the code for you to read the file, *(but you have to install [pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/))*

```
from functools import partial
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
#import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk
import pandas


def get_selected_file_name(file_menu):
    filename = file_menu.get()
    print("file selected:", filename)
    reader = pandas.read_excel(filename)  # code to read excel file
    # now you can use the `reader` object to get the file data


folder = os.path.realpath('./test_folder')
filelist = [fname for fname in os.listdir(folder)]
master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry('1200x800')
master.title('Select a file')
optmenu = ttk.Combobox(master, values=filelist, state='readonly')
optmenu.pack(fill='x')

button_select = tk.Button(master, text="Read File",
                          width=20,
                          height=7,
                          compound=tk.CENTER,
                          command=partial(get_selected_file_name, optmenu))
button_select.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
master.mainloop()
```

The window should look somewhat like this:

[image]

Comment: i need ur help on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66309595/tkinter-open-html-file-based-on-filename-in-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 1):

I'd explore using the filedialog module in tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


def load_file():
    f_in = filedialog.askopenfilename( filetypes = [ ( 'Python', '*.py' ) ])  # Change to appropriate extension.
    if len( f_in ) > 0:
        with open( f_in, 'r' ) as file:
            filedata = file.read()
        print( filedata )   # printed to the terminal for simplicity.
                            # process it as required.

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Button( root, text = 'Find File', command = load_file ).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

`askopenfilename` allows a user to navigate the folder tree to find the correct file. [Basic documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/dialog.html)