# TKinter: Open html file based on filename in dropdown menu

Tags: python, html, file, tkinter

I need help on how to open html file based on selected filename in my dropdown menu.

My problem :

when I run my code, it shows the interface like in image.
[image]

when I clicked "show data", it go directly to the other browse. it doesn't show my html file as attached image.
[image]

I just want, when I select a html file in dropdown list then click "Show Data", it will go and open my html file.

Thanks IN ADVANCE

Here is my code :

---

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
#import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk
import pandas as pd
import webbrowser
from webbrowser import open as openlink
import urllib

def open(file_menu):
    filename = file_menu.get()
    webbrowser.open(filename)



def clear_data():
    tv1.delete(*tv1.get_children())
    return None



folder = os.path.realpath(r'C:\Users\Downloads\testing')
filelist = [fname for fname in os.listdir(folder)]

master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry('1200x800')
master.title('THB')

# Frame for TreeView
frame0 = tk.LabelFrame(master, text="Chapter",background="light grey")
frame0.place(height=500, width=1200, rely=0.0, relx=0.0)

optmenu = ttk.Combobox(frame0, values=filelist, state='readonly')
optmenu.pack(fill='x')

button_select = tk.Button(frame0, text="Show Data",
                          width=15,
                          height=2,
                          compound=tk.CENTER,
                          command=partial(open, optmenu))

button_select.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
button_select.pack(side=tk.TOP)

# Frame for TreeView
frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(master, text="Data",background="light blue")
frame1.place(height=500, width=1200, rely=0.2, relx=0.0)


## Treeview Widget
tv1 = ttk.Treeview(frame1)
tv1.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1) # set the height and width of the widget to 100% of its container (frame1).

treescrolly = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="vertical", command=tv1.yview) # command means update the yaxis view of the widget
treescrollx = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="horizontal", command=tv1.xview) # command means update the xaxis view of the widget
tv1.configure(xscrollcommand=treescrollx.set, yscrollcommand=treescrolly.set) # assign the scrollbars to the Treeview Widget
treescrollx.pack(side="bottom", fill="x") # make the scrollbar fill the x axis of the Treeview widget
treescrolly.pack(side="right", fill="y") # make the scrollbar fill the y axis of the Treeview widget



master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code called `webbrowser.open(filename)` inside `open()` function and so it is expected result.  BTW, don't name your function the same as built-in function of Python.

Comment: can u help to edit my code? sorry I'm new in python

Comment: HTML file as image? What are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: i trying to open my html file in my computer using tkinter button.When I choose my html file in dropdown list, then click "show data", then it will go and open my html file. not just  open like an image above. If you can see in the image above, it just open the browser , it not open my exact html file .

Comment: Do you want to show the raw source of the HTML file actually? Then use a `Text` widget to show the source instead of using `webbrowser.open(filename)`.

Comment: i able to open my html file using this code: from tkinter import *
import webbrowser
parentwindow=Tk()
parentwindow.geometry('450x300')
parentwindow.title("THB")

def open():
    webbrowser.open(r"C:\Users\1020 CPU IPC Function Doorbell Register.htm")


    
button1=Button(parentwindow,width=20,font=("arial",15),text="open",command=open)
button1.place(x=80,y=100)
parentwindow.mainloop()

Comment: but when i use my old code, it doesnt work to display my html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just required a small change, you needed to pass the `file://` link to the browser to open it as a local file.

Else, the browser automatically thinks that the file name is a server, and thus for error, it can't open it!

The fixed part `def open(file_menu):`:

```py
def open(file_menu):
    filename = file_menu.get()

    open_in_browser_link = f"file://{os.path.join(folder, filename)}"
    print(open_in_browser_link)

    webbrowser.open(open_in_browser_link)
```

complete code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
#import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk
import pandas as pd
import webbrowser
from webbrowser import open as openlink
import urllib

def open(file_menu):
    filename = file_menu.get()

    open_in_browser_link = f"file://{os.path.join(folder, filename)}"
    print(open_in_browser_link)

    webbrowser.open(open_in_browser_link)



def clear_data():
    tv1.delete(*tv1.get_children())
    return None



folder = os.path.realpath(r'C:\Users\Downloads\testing')
filelist = [fname for fname in os.listdir(folder)]

master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry('1200x800')
master.title('THB')

# Frame for TreeView
frame0 = tk.LabelFrame(master, text="Chapter",background="light grey")
frame0.place(height=500, width=1200, rely=0.0, relx=0.0)

optmenu = ttk.Combobox(frame0, values=filelist, state='readonly')
optmenu.pack(fill='x')

button_select = tk.Button(frame0, text="Show Data",
                          width=15,
                          height=2,
                          compound=tk.CENTER,
                          command=partial(open, optmenu))

button_select.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
button_select.pack(side=tk.TOP)

# Frame for TreeView
frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(master, text="Data",background="light blue")
frame1.place(height=500, width=1200, rely=0.2, relx=0.0)


## Treeview Widget
tv1 = ttk.Treeview(frame1)
tv1.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1) # set the height and width of the widget to 100% of its container (frame1).

treescrolly = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="vertical", command=tv1.yview) # command means update the yaxis view of the widget
treescrollx = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="horizontal", command=tv1.xview) # command means update the xaxis view of the widget
tv1.configure(xscrollcommand=treescrollx.set, yscrollcommand=treescrolly.set) # assign the scrollbars to the Treeview Widget
treescrollx.pack(side="bottom", fill="x") # make the scrollbar fill the x axis of the Treeview widget
treescrolly.pack(side="right", fill="y") # make the scrollbar fill the y axis of the Treeview widget



master.mainloop()
```

> *Note: But, keep in mind, if you open some file that aren't browser supported, they may ask to open with some different application, in your computer.
> Example: If you try to open a pdf.